# Paypal - Donate option does not appear on create button

Tags: java, html, paypal, payment

I want to add the donate button to my website, when I'm creating the button, the choiceBox does not list the donation option.
[image]

How can I solve this.

Comment: If you click on "Customize text or appearance", does it give you the option to change "Add to Cart" to "Donate"? (maybe "Buy Now" is a closer analogue, but I think the whole thing is cosmetic isn't it?)

Comment: Thanks man I change it now with a donate img url. and yes it is. what shoul i use "Buy Now" or "Add to Cart"

Answer (score 3):

It may be based on the country your PayPal account is in. Not every country has the ability to create a Donate button in PayPal. If you are going to use a different button with a donate image, I suggest a Buy Now button as you can leave the price field blank in a Buy Now button if you'd like so that the user can enter their own desired amount.